# SQL Server Insert or Update Command For Duplicate Primary Keys

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert, sql-update

I have a trigger on an 'import' table that sends the normalized data to my 'main' table.
Currently, if the same data is inserted twice, the trigger deletes data found in the main table and reinserts it. While this has worked for a while, deleting what could be potentially good data seems like a bad idea.

My current code looks like this:

```
DELETE FROM [MainTable]
WHERE [DeviceSN] IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT [DeviceSN]
    FROM [ImportTable]
    INNER JOIN [MapTable] ON [ImportTable].[Component] = [MapTable].[Component] and [ImportTable].[Property] = [MapTable].[Property]
    WHERE DateAdded < [Created Date] AND [Imported] = 0
)

INSERT INTO [MainTable]
    ([DeviceSN]
    ,[Key]
    ,[Value]
SELECT
     [DeviceSN]
    ,[Key]
    ,[Value]
FROM [ImportTable]
    INNER JOIN [MapTable] ON [ImportTable].[Component] = [MapTable].[Component] and [ImportTable].[Property] = [MapTable].[Property]
    WHERE [Imported] = 0;

UPDATE [ImportTable]
SET [Imported] = 1
FROM [ImportTable]
    INNER JOIN [MapTable] ON [ImportTable].[Component] = [MapTable].[Component] and [ImportTable].[Property] = [MapTable].[Property]
    WHERE [Imported] = 0;
```

I was wondering if there was a way for me to to simply update the value where there would be a primary key constraint, rather than deleting from the main table every time.

Also,
The mapping table simply assigns a key value for each serial property. It's basically a dictionary to help normalize the data. 
And I know I should make use of pseudo tables in these triggers. This is something I plan to do.

Comment: Try to use `MERGE INTO`, this will help you with the `SCD` process

Comment: What is SCD. And is there any chance you can provide example code? I am not familiar with merge into

Comment: Alan, SCD stands for Slowly Changing Dimension, here is the reference for `merge into` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql, and you could find example there

Comment: this looks like what I need. Thanks!